# OSDictionary * Injection in IORegistry

Tags: xcode, macos, iokit, kernel-extension

I'm trying to create a new Dictionary and inject it in the IORegistry. I've managed to inject simple strings or data values but thats it.

My approach is via a modified IOPCIFamily.kext, and it's not for a specific purpose but just for learning.

My code for 1 line values is something like this

```
if (product == id){ setProperty("test", "test") }
```

and another approach

```
if (product == id){ propTable->setObject("TEST", prop) prop->release(); }
```

propTable is the Parent Dictionary, so i must create a child Dictionary to which i can inject values with setObject parameter.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? I suspect it must be something like this:

```
propTable->newTable->setObject(etc)
```

but i didn't figure how to create the newTable for propTable to insert it in the existing one of what ever product == ids it finds.

Thank you very much, sorry if it's confusing. Not used to explain code related stuff in english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the [OSDictionary::withCapacity](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/KernelIOKitFramework/OSDictionary_h/Classes/OSDictionary/index.html#//apple_ref/cpp/clm/OSDictionary/withCapacity/OSDictionary%2a/%28unsignedint%29) factory function.

For example:

```
OSDictionary* prop_dict = OSDictionary::withCapacity(1);
OSString* val = OSString::withCString("test");
if (!prop_dict || !val)
{
  // handle error...
}
prop_dict->setObject("test", val);
val->release(); val = NULL;
```

and then, to use it in you property table:

```
propTable->setObject("NewProperty", prop_dict);
prop_dict->release(); prop_dict = NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Precisely what i needed. Funny i tried something similar but without using OSString, needless to say it didn't work.